# javascript - refer method before init

Tags: javascript, init

Why does "write2" work and "write1" doesn't?

```
function Stuff() {
    this.write1 = this.method;
    this.write2 = function() {this.method();}
    this.method = function() {
        alert("testmethod");
    }
}
var stuff = new Stuff;
stuff.write1();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second one evaluates `this.method` at the time of execution of the anonymous function, while the first makes a reference copy of something that doesn't yet exist.

It can be confusing because it seems like both `write1` and `write2` attempt to use/reference something that doesn't yet exist but when you declare `write2` you are creating a closure which actually only copies a reference to `this` and then executes the body of the function later, when `this` has been modified by adding `method`

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because you're referencing `this.method` before it was declared. Change to:

```
function Stuff() {

    this.write2 = function() {this.method();}

    // First declare this.method, than this.write1.
    this.method = function() {
        alert("testmethod");
    }
    this.write1 = this.method;
}
var stuff = new Stuff;
stuff.write1();
```

Comment: Because in `write2` reference to `this.method()` is evaluated at a time of `write2()` call, at which time `this.method` is already defined.